# Checking for duplicates in a list of a class and updating values in the class in android

Tags: java, android

i have a class foo that contains NameFoo and NumberOfFoo

i have an arraylist that is a List call it fooList

i want to check if fooList has two of the same NameFoo and if it does add NumberOfFoo(0) to numberOfFoo(1) and delete NumberOfFoo(0).

so in total what i want is to check for duplicate in NameFoo and if there is add their Numbers, keep different nameFoo with updates NumberFoo but delete all the rest.

I tried a couple of things like

```
int mSize = mFoo.size();
    if(mSize>1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j < mSize; j++) {
                    if 
  (foo.get(i).getName().equals(foo.get(j).getName())) {
                        counter++;

                        foo.get(i).setNumber(String.valueOf(counter));
                    }
                }

        }
```

this returns the correct addition of numbers but will not delete the one's that has been added, now lets say i tried to do foo.remove(j) in the loop, the foo.getSize or mSize in the loop will decrease and it will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

It's fun to solve these things, but i am missing it this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using java-7 below is an example with your problem, converting List to Map with unique keys and duplicate values, and them sum the `fooNumber` and convert into `List`

**Foo.java**

```
class Foo{
private String nameFoo;

private String numberOfFoo;

public Foo() {}

public Foo(String nameFoo, String numberOfFoo) {
    this.nameFoo=nameFoo;
    this.numberOfFoo=numberOfFoo;

}

public String getNameFoo() {
    return nameFoo;
}

public void setNameFoo(String nameFoo) {
    this.nameFoo = nameFoo;
}

public String getNumberOfFoo() {
    return numberOfFoo;
}

public void setNumberOfFoo(String numberOfFoo) {
    this.numberOfFoo = numberOfFoo;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Foo [nameFoo=" + nameFoo + ", numberOfFoo=" + numberOfFoo + "]";
   }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Foo f1 = new Foo();
f1.setNameFoo("tony");
f1.setNumberOfFoo(100);
Foo f2 = new Foo();
f2.setNameFoo("tony");
f2.setNumberOfFoo(200);
Foo f3 = new Foo();
f3.setNameFoo("cap");
f3.setNumberOfFoo(500);
List<Foo> l = Arrays.asList(f1,f2,f3);
Map<String,List<Foo>> m = new HashMap<>();
List<Foo> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(Foo f:l) {
    if(m.get(f.getNameFoo())==null) {
        List<Foo> templist = new ArrayList<>();
        templist.add(f);
        m.put(f.getNameFoo(), templist);
    }else {
        List<Foo> list =m.get(f.getNameFoo());
        list.add(f);
        m.put(f.getNameFoo(), list);
    }
}
for(String s : m.keySet()) {
    Foo fin = new Foo();
    Integer fooNumber =0;
    for(Foo foo : m.get(s)) {
        fooNumber = fooNumber+Integer.valueOf(foo.getNumberOfFoo());
        fin.setNameFoo(foo.getNameFoo());
        fin.setNumberOfFoo(fooNumber.toString());
    }
    result.add(fin);
}
System.out.println(result); //[Foo [nameFoo=tony, numberOfFoo=300], Foo [nameFoo=cap, numberOfFoo=500]]

  }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer, although its not accepted. because i asked for android specifically because of that :)
+ if you notice the NumberFoo was a string.

Comment: I will make that change it is so simple and for understanding purpose i added with clear example

Comment: Im sorry my reputation does not allow the upvote, yes your answer works perfectly in Eclipse. but in AS oldvalue+newvalue will be two objects getting added, so it will not work, + it takes API 24 to add Collectors. 
Thank you.

Comment: Update without java-8 check it @KARAMJABER